# How to send firebase notifications using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I want to implement push notifications automatically and I've used javascript (node.js) but I got this error

```
Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value
```

I am not node js developer I am a flutter developer and I don't know what is promises.

this is my code:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');


admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

var notificationMessageData;

exports.fcmTester = functions.firestore.document('posts/{postID}').onCreate((snapshot , context) => {
    notificationMessageData = snapshot.data();

    admin.firestore().collection('pushTokens').get().then(async (snapshot) => {
        var tokens = [];

        if (snapshot.empty) {
            console.log('No Devices');
        } else {
            for (var token of snapshot.docs) {
                tokens.push(token.data().tokenID);
            }

            var payload = {
                "notification": {
                    "title": "from" + notificationMessageData.writer,
                    "body": "from" + notificationMessageData.name,
                    "sound": "default"
                },
                "data": {
                    "sendername": notificationMessageData.writer,
                    "message": notificationMessageData.name
                }
            }

            return await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens , payload).then((response) => {
                console.log('nice');
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            })
        }
    })
})
```

Everything is going okay and I upload it without any problem but when adding a document to the posts collection it outputs in the logs the above error.

I have created a user registration form and I've registered the users and put their token id in a collection called pushTokens and then sending a notification for each user inside that collection but this didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

1. You don't return the promises returned by the asynchronous Firebase methods (`get()` and `sendToDevice()`);
2. You mix-up the use of `async/await` with the [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method.

I would suggest you watch the 3 official videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the [Firebase video series](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/), and then that you first try with using the `then()` method to correctly [chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) your Promises and return the chain.

The following code should work.

```
exports.fcmTester = functions.firestore.document('posts/{postID}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const notificationMessageData = snapshot.data();

    return admin.firestore().collection('pushTokens').get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            var tokens = [];

            if (snapshot.empty) {
                console.log('No Devices');
                throw new Error('No Devices');
            } else {
                for (var token of snapshot.docs) {
                    tokens.push(token.data().tokenID);
                }

                var payload = {
                    "notification": {
                        "title": "from" + notificationMessageData.writer,
                        "body": "from" + notificationMessageData.name,
                        "sound": "default"
                    },
                    "data": {
                        "sendername": notificationMessageData.writer,
                        "message": notificationMessageData.name
                    }
                }

                return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload)
            }

        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            return null;
        })

});
```

---

Then, after having experienced the "management" of asynchronous methods with `then()` (and `catch()`), you may give a try with `async/await`: again, this [official video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jr7pDZ1RAUg) from Doug Stevenson will be of great help.

Comment: @thecoder Hi, did you have the opportunity to look at thIs answer? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

It says:

```js
Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value
```

Have you tried returning `null`, or `true` or `false`, etc. from your functions?

A promise is something you pass around your program while you wait for it to become a real value.

It seems like the error message is focused on wanting you to return something from your function. Without knowing more, this is the best advice I can give.

Comment: I've done as you've mentioned but nothing still works and it gives me the same error